# What is an idiomatic expression?

Tags: idiomatic-language

"I got up early as I had an errand to run. Then I got back home. I felt rather sleepy so I decided to **have one-hour sleepin / take one-hour nap**."

Which would sound correct? If neither, provide a natural one. Thank you in advance

Comment: Off-topic. Look up 'sleep in' and 'nap' in a dictionary, you'll see the difference.

Comment: If you _sleep in_, you stay in bed longer than usual. A _nap_ is a period of sleep taken during the day. You could say "I decided to go back to bed/ take a nap for an hour."

Answer (score 0):

The most idiomatic phrasing (at least in American English) would be either:

> I decided to take an hour-long nap.

Or:

> I decided to nap for an hour.

Comment: thanks. glad there are a few sane people on this forum :) hope at least this comment doesn't get deleted